# Should I use v-show with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I know that "v-if" must avoid with "v-for" but not sure about "v-show" because it is just to toggle the display attribute.
This is the code in case anyone wants to know. Basically, I try to switch 3 different types of filter list. The code runs fine but I just wanna know if it should be avoid like "v-if".

```vuejs
<template>
<button
  v-for="(filter, index) in filterList" :key="index"
  @click="chosenFilter = filter.name"
>
  {{ filter.name }}
</button>
<div
  v-for="(filter, index) in filterList" :key="index"
  v-show="chosenFilter === filter.name"
>
  <div v-for="(listItem, index) in filter.list" :key="index">
    {{ listItem }}
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

```vuejs
<script>
data () {
    return {
      filterList: [
        { name: 'Type 1', list: [] },
        { name: 'Type 2', list: [] },
        { name: 'Type 3', list: [] }
      ],
      chosenFilter: 'Type 1'
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: what your showing in the div with 2 for loops, you could simply do by setting chosenFilter to the clicked item `@click="chosenFilter = filter"`, then just output chosenFilter like any other model

Answer (score 1):

From the official style guide: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential
There are 2 points in which it's not a good practice to use that, the 2nd one is interesting: `To avoid rendering a list if it should be hidden`. This one is basically fine since you're not doing heavy JS rendering, just basic CSS toggling.
So yeah, I'd say it's correct to have a `v-show` (and ESlint is not complaining btw).

But IMO, you can solve this kind of behavior in pretty much all cases with a computed: your `filter button` could be selected with an ID and your list rendering could be filtered with a `filter` here.

Replace `@click="chosenFilter = filter.name"` with `@click="chooseFilter` and get the ID (thanks to `$event`) of the item you've clicked on, then filter your list with the selected filter.